# How Can pass order Total to (amount: { total: '0.01', currency: 'USD' } ) in paypal

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I have implemented paypal checkout express button in my asp.net web page. how can i pass orderTotal  to amount: { total: '0.01', currency: 'USD' }. by default it is '0.01' I want display actual orderTotal . 
This is my code
   paypal.Button.render({

```
                                                 env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

                                                 // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
                                                 // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create
                                                 client: {
                                                     sandbox: 'AZDxjDScFpQtjWTOUtWKbyN_bDt4OgqaF4eYXlewfBP4-8aqX3PiV8e1GWU6liB2CUXlkA59kJXE7M6R',
                                                     //production: 'AVSYgEO5SUewyQ_We4dW5uCXyEZHgcFDfKK15gCqsd7o0edVH5UOhtHK7n2uqkFQOYtjJt0vvemfgNwg'
                                                 },

                                                 // Show the buyer a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow
                                                 commit: true,

                                                 // payment() is called when the button is clicked
                                                 payment: function (data, actions) {

                                                     // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
                                                     return actions.payment.create({
                                                         payment: {
                                                             transactions: [
                                                            {
                                                                amount: { total: '0.01', currency: 'USD' }
                                                            }
                                                             ]
                                                         }
                                                     });
                                                 },
                                                 commit: true,
                                                 // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
                                                 onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
                                                     // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
                                                     return actions.payment.execute().then(function () {
                                                         //window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                                                         onPaypalAuthorize();
                                                     });
                                                 }

                                             }, '#paypal-button-container');
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending whether you are using Forms or MVC.

For web forms you can use the inline directive
`<% =MyTotal %>` where you would like the total.

With MVC
@model.MyTotal would work where MyTotal would be the total you would like to pass to paypal.

For example, WebForms

```
amount: { total: <% =MyTotal %>, currency: 'USD' }
```

MVC

```
amount: { total: @Model.MyTotal, currency: 'USD' }
```

A couple of things that need to be pointed out.  The total needs to be a string, and it needs to be rounded to two decimal points.  If you fail to do this, it will kick back and error.