# pass amount total to PayPal express checkout

Tags: javascript, asp.net, paypal, webforms, paypal-sandbox

I have the express checkout button on my ASP.NET webforms webpage but can't seem to figure out how to pass the total variable (stored in a label on the page) to the PayPal popup when the button is clicked.

I know this question has been asked already ([How Can pass order Total to (amount: { total: '0.01', currency: 'USD' } ) in paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45957973/how-can-pass-order-total-to-amount-total-0-01-currency-usd-in-pay)) but the answer makes little sense to me and doesn't go into as much detail as I need as a beginner programmer.

```js
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
     <script>
        paypal.Button.render({
            env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production
            style: {
                label: 'pay',
                size: 'small', // small | medium | large | responsive
                shape: 'rect',   // pill | rect
                color: 'gold'   // gold | blue | silver | black
            },
            // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
            // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create
            client: {
                sandbox:    'AWDwdGr-KZK4jJi0WBUZmFowgG6oCtLpNDxtXuiOfAT1UdNUYeSlvoXYkrKW7SRdcYqqjHCo7IcYPmJf',
                production: 'Production ClientID'
            },
            // payment() is called when the button is clicked
            payment: function(data, actions) {
                // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
                return actions.payment.create({
                    payment: {
                        transactions: [
                            {
                                amount: { total: '0.01' , currency: 'EUR' }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            },
            // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
            onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

                // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
                return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                    window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                });
            }
        }, '#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
```

Could someone please give me some guidance on how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer you linked does explain this pretty well but as you wanted more explanation, in WebForms you can use asp.net inline server tags to access elements from your page as long as they are on an aspx file. The syntax is as follows:

```
<%=ElementName.Property%>
```

This allows you to either access the value directly or assign it to a javascript variable. In your case either should work fine, for elements such as labels and things that contain text the property you are looking for will generally be innerHTML or innerText, so the following should give you the result you need:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
     <script>
        paypal.Button.render({
            env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production
            style: {
                label: 'pay',
                size: 'small', // small | medium | large | responsive
                shape: 'rect',   // pill | rect
                color: 'gold'   // gold | blue | silver | black
            },
            // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
            // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create
            client: {
                sandbox:    'AWDwdGr-KZK4jJi0WBUZmFowgG6oCtLpNDxtXuiOfAT1UdNUYeSlvoXYkrKW7SRdcYqqjHCo7IcYPmJf',
                production: 'Production ClientID'
            },
            // payment() is called when the button is clicked
            payment: function(data, actions) {
                // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
                return actions.payment.create({
                    payment: {
                        transactions: [
                            {
                                amount: { total: '<%=TheNameOfYourLabel.innerText%>' , currency: 'EUR' }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            },
            // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
            onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

                // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
                return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                    window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                });
            }
        }, '#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
```